# Expanding an alphanumeric range given a list

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of alphanumeric items:

```
values=['1111X0-1111X3', 'A111X0-A111X3',...., ]
```

I would like to expand the last digit of every item in this list such that:

```
values_output = ['111X0', '111X1', '111X2', '111X3', 'A111X0', 'A111X1', 'A111X2', 'A111X3',...' ',...]
```

I found this answer on a similar post that uses regex:

```
import re

lst = ['4276-4279', 'I69-I71', 'V104-V112', '11528']
new = []
for l in lst:
    m = re.match(r'^([A-Z]*)(\d+)-\1(\d+)$', l)
    if m:
        new += [m.group(1) + str(i) for i in range(int(m.group(2)), int(m.group(3))+1)]
    else:
        new += [l]

print(new)
```

However I could not figure out a pattern to match the items on my list.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.search(r'^(\w+?)(\d+)-\1(\d+)$', l)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0w4SAO).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\w+?)` - Group 1: any one or more word chars as few as possible
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\1` - Group 1 value
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.